# Why null doesn't work in .prototype of constructor

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am currently learning JavaScript on [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/) and I came across this statement:
[image: Statement]
Link to the statement:
[statement](https://javascript.info/function-prototype#:%7E:text=The%20value%20of%20F.prototype%20should%20be%20either%20an%20object%20or%20null%3A%20other%20values%20won%E2%80%99t%20work.) 
But when I try this code with `null` in `.prototype` of constructor:

```
function Rabbit() {
    this.name = 'rabbit';
}

Rabbit.prototype = null; // *

let obj = new Rabbit();

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)); // [Object: null prototype] {}
```

I get `Object.prototype` as a `[[Prototype]]` of instance and not `null`. 
And actually it works for every value if it's not object, for example here `[[Prototype]]` of obj will be also `Object.prototype`:

```
function Rabbit() {
    this.name = 'rabbit';
}

Rabbit.prototype = 5; // *

let obj = new Rabbit();

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)); // [Object: null prototype] {}
```

And when I have object `.prototype` it works as it should:

```
function Rabbit() {
    this.name = 'rabbit';
}

Rabbit.prototype = {
    eats: true,
}; // *

let obj = new Rabbit();

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)); // { eats: true }
```

So why it works like that? Am I wrong and don't understand something?

Comment: It's not clear why they mention `null`. Any value other than an object "won't work", i.e. it will be ignored and `Object.prototype` will be used instead. Maybe they meant that *if* you want that behaviour, you *should* use `null` instead of an arbitrary value? But it definitely needs improvement, you may want to write the authors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assign any value that is not an object to the `prototype` property of a function, the object created as a result of calling that function as a constructor function (with the `new` keyword) gets `Object.prototype` as its prototype.

From [MDN - Function: prototype:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype)

> If the prototype of a function is reassigned with something other than an Object, when the function is called with new, the returned object's prototype would be Object.prototype instead. (In other words, new ignores the prototype property and constructs a plain object.)

If you want to ensure that the newly created object doesn't inherit anything from `Object.prototype`, you can use the [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) as shown below:

```
Rabbit.prototype = Object.create(null);
```

This will set the prototype of `Rabbit.prototype` to `null`.

Comment: Maybe one should add that `Object.getPrototypeOf(new Rabbit())` will then still not return null and that one can achieve this (if one really insists) by letting the constructor function `Rabbit` ignore the `this`, create a new object with `Object.create(null)` as you said, do the object-initialization on this new object and then explicitly return it from the constructor. For consistency it would then be fair to set `Rabbit.prototype=null`, even if that will have no consequences.